# Consequences of $NP=coNP=BPP=RP$

Tags: complexity-theory

What is complexity theoretic implication of following possibilities - $NP=coNP=BPP=RP$ or $coNP\neq NP=BPP=RP$ (consensus is these seem impossible)?

Comment: NP = coNP = RP $\;\; \implies \;\;$ NP ​ = ​ NP ∩ NP ​ = ​ NP ∩ cocoNP ​ = ​ RP ∩ coRP ​ = ​ ZPP $\hspace{1.44 in}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious (it is getting late here), the second isn't possible - $BPP = coBPP$, so $NP=BPP \rightarrow NP = coBPP \rightarrow NP = coNP$.

In the first case, some of the consequences would be:

- "Feasible" algorithms for $NP$-complete problems, for at least the randomised version of feasible.
- $PH \subseteq NP$
- Unless $P = NP$, adding randomness adds computational power.
- Strong pseudorandom number generators do not exist (nor do one way functions). (we would need $BPP = P$ for them to exist, but that would imply $P=NP$, in which case they don't).

Comment: (Even without the OP's assumptions,) If $\: P = NP \:$ then strong pseudorandom number generators still do not exist. $\;\;\;$ Proof: $\:$ If $\: P = NP \:$ then one can efficiently decide the range of circuits, in which case when the codomain is significantly larger than the domain, one can efficiently distinguish the uniform distribution on the codomain from arbitrary distributions on the range. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, so no SPRNGs either way...

Comment: So $NP=BPP\iff co-NP=co-BPP$?

Comment: @Turbo, yes, assume $\Pi \in BPP$, and hence $\overline{\Pi} \in coBPP = BPP$. If $BPP = NP$, then $\Pi \in NP$, and hence $\overline{\Pi} \in coNP$ but as $coBPP=BPP=NP$, we have $\overline{\Pi} \in NP$, so $NP = coNP$.

Comment: $\overline{\Pi}\in coNP\backslash coBPP$ could be a possibility? So I do not follow your statement after second "hence.....".

Comment: @Turbo every problem in $BPP$ is in $NP$ (obviously), but we also have that the complement of every problem in $NP$ (which by definition is in $coNP$) is also in $BPP$ (because $coBPP = BPP$), and hence in $NP$, and thus every problem in $coNP$ is also in $NP$, thus the equality.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Impagliazzo's 5 worlds [1], especially Algorithmica. In Algorithmica, $\sf P = NP$, or some "moral equivalent" of that holds, like $\sf NP = RP$.

You might also be interested in a relevant question on [CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/19949/5693).

---

[1] [Russell Impagliazzo. A Personal View of Average-Case Complexity. 1995 Complexity Conference.](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/ri5svetu.pdf)